# Работа с XML в MS SQL?

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server, xquery

Допустим, есть XML такого вида:

```
<root>
<TableRow>
<field1></field1>
<field2></field2>
<field3></field3>
</TableRow>
<TableRow>
<field1></field1>
<field2></field2>
<field3></field3>
</TableRow>
</root>
```

Можно ли получить выборку такого вида?

```
value
---------------
значение field1
значение field2
значение field3
значение field1
значение field2
значение field3
```

Можно ли это сделать без явного перечисления названия узлов? Допустим, известно, что все узлы field+цифра. Можно ли сделать запрос по маске?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете отфильтровать узлы с нужными именами с помощью функций `local-name` и `substring`:

```
declare @xml xml = N'
<root>
  <TableRow>
    <field1>value 1</field1>
    <field2>value 2</field2>
    <field3>value 3</field3>
    <not_a_field>AA</not_a_field>
  </TableRow>
  <TableRow>
    <field1>value 4</field1>
    <field2>value 5</field2>
    <field3>value 6</field3>
    <not_a_field>BB</not_a_field>
  </TableRow>
</root>';

select x.c.value('text()[1]', 'varchar(20)') value
from @xml.nodes('/root[1]/TableRow/*[substring(local-name(), 0, 6)="field"]') x(c);
```

Результат:

```
value
--------
value 1
value 2
value 3
value 4
value 5
value 6
```

В XQuery запросах использовать `*` в XPath (также как и выражения наподобие `'//field'`), если без них можно обойтись, не рекомендуется. Если выбираете узлы от корня, то лучше указать `'/root[1]'` в начале XPath. Если точно известен путь до узлов - указывайте его явно. Если берёте значение из элемента, то лучше взять его не через `.`, а через `text()[1]`. Чем больше информации об узлах вы дадите XQuery процессору, тем проще будет ему распарсить xml и тем ниже будет стоимость запроса.

В данном случае, например, оценочная стоимость такого запроса

```
select x.c.value('text()[1]', 'varchar(20)') value
from @xml.nodes('/root[1]/TableRow/*[substring(local-name(), 0, 6)="field"]') x(c);
```

и такого

```
select x.c.value('.', 'varchar(20)') value
from @xml.nodes('*/*/*[substring(local-name(), 0, 6)="field"]') x(c);
```

соотносятся примерно как 2 к 136.

Answer (score 3):

Должен сработать такой запрос:

```
select x.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
from [TableName]
cross apply [XmlField].nodes('*/*/*') t(x);
```

В выражении `*/*/*` каждая звездочка соответствует любому имени на данном уровне вложенности.